# Count documents by the average of its fields in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, average

Our students' scores in 4 fields are modeled like this:

```
{
    "_id" : xxx,
    "student" : "Private Ryan",
    "math" : 9,
    "history" : 8,
    "literature" : 6,
    "science" : 10  
}
```

The task is to do count how many `good/average/bad` performed students there are. Given:

- Good : having `average >= 8` point
- Bad : having `average score < 5`.

If possible, bucket them would be nice too.

Comment: Could you at least show your attempt and if possible with some sample documents and the expected output example? Is this average across all subjects per student or per subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to define "label" for every student. To apply conditional logic you can take advantage of [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/index.html) or double [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html). Then you need to run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to count them and also you can use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/index.html) to get entire documents in final result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            label: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { 
                        avg: { 
                            $divide: [ { $sum: [ "$math", "$history", "$literature", "$science" ] }, 4 ] 
                        } 
                    },
                    in: { 
                        $cond: [ 
                            { $gte: [ "$$avg", 8 ] }, 
                            "good", 
                            { $cond: [ { $lt: [ "$$avg", 5 ] }, "bad", "average" ] } 
                        ] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$label",
            count: { $sum: 1 },
            students: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4euCRykSQFk)

Comment: The explanation is clear and the result is exactly what I want ( but did not know how to achieve). It is also very fast on my dev DB, But I guess it would also be acceptably fast with around 10 millions documents